# php update multiple row

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

how do i update multiple row with one query?

```
table
id   ref_no   name
-------------------
1              a
2              b
3              c
4              e
5              f
...................
```

since i just created new `ref_no` column and its blank. and i expect the column `id = ref_no`

i tried below but giving me same ids:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT id_user FROM user");
while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
    $db->query("UPDATE user SET user_no='".$r['id']."'");
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with mysql only

```
UPDATE table_name SET ref_no = id
```

Comment: is it possible like to append ref in front it? ie: ref1, ref2, etc. `$db->query("UPDATE user SET ref_no=AE'".$r['id']."' where id=".$r['id']);` not sure it would work?

Comment: you can do that `UPDATE table_name SET ref_no = CONCAT('ref',id)`

Answer (score 2):

Do you want every row to have the same value in the ref_no columan as in the id column? In this case you can use

```
UPDATE user SET ref_no = id
```

but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for...

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE user
SET ref_no = id
WHERE ref_no IS NULL
```

Be aware that, in SQL context, `blank` is a special concept that represented by the NULL keyword. You have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` to test against NULL.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think the other answers is what you want. If you need the id of each row to be equal to the ref:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT id_user FROM user");
while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
    $db->query("UPDATE user SET ref_no='".$r['id']."' where id=".$r['id']);
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
UPDATE user SET ref_no = id
```